# How BeveledRectangleBorder for TextField in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, flutter-layout

I have TextField i need to change the border Corners Cut, I have try to do with wrap TextField on Container and apply  BeveledRectangleBorder but is not proper.

[image]

Please suggest me how can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

After searching a little i've found the source code of that design you shared with me. They have build a custom input border (`CutCornersBorder`) for that particular style. You can use that file and add that to your theme to get that look of your TextField without adding any extra code.

[CutCornersBorder](https://github.com/Bryanmuloni/Flutter-Shrine/blob/master/lib/supplemental/cut_corners_border.dart)

```
return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
      theme: ThemeData(
        inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(border: CutCornersBorder()),
      ),
    );
```

[Full Preview](https://dartpad.dev/8d7b753717beb4666ae8d0ddb337d496)

**OLD**

You can do it by creating your own custom painter implementation.

**FlatCorneredBackgroundPainter**

```
class FlatCorneredBackgroundPainter extends CustomPainter {
  double radius, strokeWidth;
  Color strokeColor;

  FlatCorneredBackgroundPainter(
      {this.radius = 10, this.strokeWidth = 4, this.strokeColor = Colors.blue});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    double w = size.width;
    double h = size.height;

    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..color = strokeColor;

    Path path = Path()
      ..addPolygon([
        Offset(radius, 0),
        Offset(w - radius, 0),
        Offset(w, radius),
        Offset(w, h - radius),
        Offset(w - radius, h),
        Offset(radius, h),
        Offset(0, h - radius),
        Offset(0, radius),
      ], true);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: FlatCorneredBackgroundPainter(radius: 10.0, strokeColor: Colors.red, strokeWidth: 2),
          child: Container(
            width: 300,
            height: 70,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have tried your answer it is working fine in Container for get Corner Cut border, but for TextField it is not working so please if possible for the TextField then help me.

Comment: just add the TextField inside container.. I've updated my code too

Comment: can you show me the exact design you are trying to achieve?

Comment: thank you so much, this efforts are really appreciated